# AS3 ByteArray writeObject() XMLList is null

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, xmllist

Why isn't my XMLList writing to my ByteArray?

```
var suspendData:ByteArray=new ByteArray();

var _questions:XMLList=model.questions;

suspendData.writeObject(_questions);// only writes 3 bytes
```

and when I attempt to read it back in it's null.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the simple fix is to convert your XML to a string first.

If you post more code, I might be able to tell you why though.

Comment: I hoping to keep it as an XMLList and not convert to a string.

There's not much more to the code. model.questions in not null.

here's the code for the read...

var _questions:XMLList= suspendData.readObject() as XMLList;

Comment: as XMLList will return a null object if the cast fails, try XMLList(suspendData.readObject())